# How can I set the refresh_token when working with the google api?

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I'm working off an example trying to learn how to use the google api to change events on a calendar.  The server is the user which will update the calendar based off of information in a database.  No user interaction is actually required.

The problem is I am having issues getting/using refresh tokens.  I click the "Connect Me" link that gets added to the page and it gives me an error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_request", "error_description" : "Missing required parameter: refresh_token" }`

I have [tried setting the refresh token this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15905618/2930045), along with similar methods, but none of them seem to work which makes me think I am implementing them incorrectly.

When I print out the `$_SESSION['access_token']` variable, it shows no `refresh_token`:

`{"access_token":"token","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3599,"created":1417534503}`

Here is the function I am using to authorize the 'user' without the `refresh_token` portion(based off an example):

```
function googleAuth(){

    $client_id = 'myclientid';
    $client_secret = 'myclientsecret';
    $redirect_uri = 'redirecturi';
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setClientId($client_id);
    $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
    $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar');

    /************************************************
    If we're logging out we just need to clear our
    local access token in this case
    ************************************************/
    if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
    }
    /************************************************
    If we have a code back from the OAuth 2.0 flow,
    we need to exchange that with the authenticate()
    function. We store the resultant access token
    bundle in the session, and redirect to ourself.
    ************************************************/
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $resp = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

        $redirect = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

    }
    /************************************************
    If we have an access token, we can make
    requests, else we generate an authentication URL.
    ************************************************/
    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    } else {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    }

    if (isset($authUrl)) {
        echo "<a class='login' href='" . $authUrl . "'>Connect Me!</a>";
    }

    return $client;
}
```

Here is the code I am using to add the event to the calendar:

```
function addEvent($title, $location, $startTime, $stopTime, $client){

    $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
    $start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();

    $event->setSummary($title);
    $event->setLocation($location);

    $start->setDateTime($startTime);

    $end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();

    $end->setDateTime($stopTime);

    $event->setStart($start);
    $event->setEnd($end);

    $atendee = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee();
    $atendee->setEmail('someGuy@someDomain.com');

    $atendees = array($atendee);

    $event->attendees = $atendees;

    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

    $event_id = $service->events->insert('primary', $event);

}
```

How can I set the missing parameter: "refresh_token"?  Are there issues with the structure of the code?  I have looked through documentation, and I am willing to look some more, but if somebody can lend a hand at explaining how to do this, that would be amazing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if the token has a refresh-token (if you request offline access, the refresh-token will be sent with the access token the first time).

Something like this

```
 $token = $client->getAccessToken();
 $authObj = json_decode($token);
 if(isset($authObj->refresh_token)) {
     save_refresh_token($authObj->refresh_token);
 }
```

Where save_refresh_token saves your refresh-token somewhere (db).

Then you can check if token as expired by:

```
 $client->isAccessTokenExpired()
```

If it is, you can update it with:

```
$client->refreshToken($your_saved_refresh_token);
```

And then set your new access token to the session:

```
 $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
```

Comment: Good! I guess the issue is that you only get the refresh token the first time. If you deauthorize the app and connect again it will be there.