# Add events to my google calendar from my website

Tags: php, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I have created a php page with fullcalendar jquery plugin which allow website users to book time. On background I'm storing event into my DB and then using Google calendar API creating same event to my google calendar.

But my implementation is asking user to login into their google account and creating event on user's calendar. How can I achieve to create user event in my(website owner's) google calendar "seamlessly"?

my code is as below:

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Google Calendar');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/calendar-php-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/calendar-php-quickstart.json
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR)
));


/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient() {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
    $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
    $client->setAuthConfigFile(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
    $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);

/*if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
  $accessToken = file_get_contents($credentialsPath);
} else {*/

    if(!$_REQUEST['code']) {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        //printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
        header("Location:".$authUrl);
    }
    $authCode = $_REQUEST['code'];
    $accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);

    // Store the credentials to disk.
    /*if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
      mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $accessToken);*/
    //printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
//}
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

// Refresh the token if it's expired.
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
$client->refreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $client->getAccessToken());
}
return $client;
}
/**
* Expands the home directory alias '~' to the full path.
* @param string $path the path to expand.
* @return string the expanded path.
*/
function expandHomeDirectory($path) {
  $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
  if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
    $homeDirectory = getenv("HOMEDRIVE") . getenv("HOMEPATH");
  }
  return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
}

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);


$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => $_SESSION['cal-data']['fname']." ".$_SESSION['cal-data']['lname'],
  'location' => $_SESSION['cal-data']['address'],
  'description' => "Contact: ".$_SESSION['cal-data']['phoneno']." for ".$_SESSION['cal-data']['title'],
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => $_SESSION['cal-data']['starttm'],
    //'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => $_SESSION['cal-data']['endtm'],
    //'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  /*'recurrence' => array(
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ),*/
  'attendees' => array(
    array('email' => $_SESSION['cal-data']['email'])
  ),
  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
    'overrides' => array(
      array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
      array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
    ),
  ),
));

$calendarId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com';
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
//printf('Event created: %s\n', $event->htmlLink);
unset($_SESSION['cal-data']);

header("Location: next-page.php");
```

Comment: There should be a setting to make it public, no? I've never worked with those, but assume there would be.

Comment: Yes there is setting to make your calendar public and my calendar is already public.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to store credentials in a shared/public calendar, using the calendar id as in the "normal" API call.

`POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/YOUR_SHARED_CALENDAR_ID/events`

BUT, you have to share a calendar with those people or with the public. https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en

Otherwise you can't

Comment: can you help me in my code where should I make api call as you suggested?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Service account to serve as a proxy user accessing your Calendar (no more prompting users to login their account). Based on [Inserting Google Calendar Entries with Service Account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26067547/5995040), You can add an event to a shared calendar.

Here is the steps:

1. [Create a Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount)
2. You need to create a public/private key pair.

> In the Create service account window, type a name for the service account and select Furnish a new private key. If you want to grant Google Apps domain-wide authority to the service account, also select Enable Google Apps Domain-wide Delegation.

**Note:** [Enable the API](https://console.developers.google.com/) and share the Calendar to your email address from the service account credentials. And don't forget to enable "Changes to events".