To block google calendar of the users after creating an event in ROR(Ruby on rails)
I am working at an ed-tech platform where we need to integrate Google Calendar services. We are using Ruby on Rails (RoR) for this integration. While we are able to create events, we are facing issues with automatically blocking participants' Google calendars. Currently, participants receive an email about the event, and their calendar is only blocked if they manually allow the event to be added. However, we want to block their calendar as soon as the event is created.
We are primarily using Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService and Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event to create events. Can you help? Do we need to use a particular service to achieve this? Please provide a solution.

I would encourage you to look more into Google APIs and understand it more. Maybe this will also help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064095/inserting-google-calendar-entries-with-service-account

That would require that the participants allow your application write access to their Google Calendars. Is it reasonable that they would allow this?
